# How to pass Einstein Email Recommendations sku to get results from item-related scenarios?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein-recommendations

I want to make Email Recommendation based on View View scenario which requires SKU.

According to that page: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_einstein_recommendation_scenarios.htm&type=5 I need to pass "somehow" SKU to *email HTML content*.

I know how to make it in Web Recommendations but how to make it in email? Something like this does not work:

https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/HASH/i/1/%%emailaddr%%?SKU=examplesku

Any idea how to pass it correctly? Or only user / site related recommendations are possible in email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be ?item=XXXX

this is covered in the [help docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_customize_the_calls.htm&type=5)

> item:  This unique identifier for your product or content must match the unique key in the catalog and the value sent in the trackPageView collect item variable. This parameter is required to make a product- or content-based recommendation on any page.

Comment: Hi EazyE, thanks. It is correct, /rr/v2/HASH/i/1/%%emailaddr%%?item=examplesku works